# How to have a projectile appear in a single spot in love

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm currently creating a game using the Love2d engine in Lua and I was wondering if it was possible to make something like a projectile appear in a single spot. Like a hero casting a flame column on an enemy that's 50px ahead of them. Ideally the flame column would appear, damage the enemy, then disappear, which this could all happen within a frame. So far the code I have is follows:

```
local function addProj()
  local speed = dt
  for i, projectile in ipairs(proj) do
    if playerBack == true then 
      projectile.y = projectile.y - 250*speed
        if projectile.y < player.y - 150 then
          table.remove(proj,i)
        end
   elseif playerForward == true then
     projectile.y = projectile.y + 250*speed
      if projectile.y > player.y + 150 then
         table.remove(proj,i)
      end
   elseif playerLeft == true then
     projectile.x = projectile.x - 250*speed
       if projectile.x < player.x - 150 then
         table.remove(proj,i)
       end
   elseif playerRight == true then
     projectile.x = projectile.x + 250*speed
       if projectile.x > player.x + 150 then
         table.remove(proj,i)
       end
    end
  end
end
```

The code above is just a workaround right now, but it basically moves the projectile a certain distance in a given direction then makes it dissappear. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so the best way to do this is to set world callbacks and test for collisions. there are good tutorials, examples, and documentation. Essentially what this will allow you to do, is get your program sentient to collisions of physics objects.

[Tutorial for the callbacks](https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:PhysicsCollisionCallbacks)

[page for the creation of the callbacks](https://love2d.org/wiki/World:setCallbacks)

If you want to do it manually like some people do with the base physics, you could place all the objects in a table, and every update you'd check the table to see if their x or y values match up, which obviously on larger games would slow the game down.